# How to prevent Visual Studio 2019 from changing tabs to spaces?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I can't find any way to make Visual Studio 2019 to keep tabs.

I've searched the internet for a bit and looked in settings, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the "Tools" menu,
select the "Options..." command.

Select the "Text Editor" item in the list on the left-hand side.

Scroll down to the "Python" item.
Select it and select "Tabs."

Then, in the right-hand panel, select the "Keep Tabs" radio-button control, as shown below:

[image]

The method is similar for other supported languages, such as C++ and C#.

Comment: That worked, along with deactivating "Use adaptive formatting", but I'll go ahead and accept it.